# How to execute commands before suspend and after resume in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, suspend, systemd, resume

can anyone help me with an example script for executing commands at suspend and resume? (for ubuntu 20.04)

I have tried to put scripts into
/lib/systemd/system-sleep (following various posts) but that did not work (journalctl -u systemd-suspend.service returns errors such as "Failed to execute /lib/systemd/system-sleep/999_pre-suspend.sh: Not a directory" or "/lib/systemd/system-sleep/999_pre-suspend failed with exit status 1.")

[addendum] I have edited:

```
sudo gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/hdparm
```

such that date and some info is written into ~/tmp/suspend.txt, and a beep tone is generated (using the command speaker-test).

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  pre)
    echo "$(date) - $1: test pre" >> /home/stefan/tmp/suspend.txt
    ( speaker-test -t sine -f 500 )& pid=$! ; sleep 0.1s ; kill -9 $pid
    ;;
  post)
    /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm resume
    echo "$(date) - $1: test post" >> /home/stefan/tmp/suspend.txt
    ( speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 )& pid=$! ; sleep 0.1s ; kill -9 $pid
    ;;
esac
```

This produces output in the suspend.txt:
ma. 15. feb. 09:54:28 +0100 2021 - pre: test pre
ma. 15. feb. 09:55:09 +0100 2021 - post: test post

BUT it does /not/ produce any tone.

Any ideas how I can make this work?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the script executable? `sudo chmod +x {file}` if you haven’t done so already.

Comment: yes, it is executable, ownership is mine (user & group).